# Does IdentityServer4 work with .NETFramework

Tags: identityserver4, .net-framework-version

I have an existing application in .NETFramework 4.6.1. I need to convert to a WebAPI to be consumed by external clients. I have been recommended to use IdentityServer4 for authorisation, however all the documentation I can find only mentions .NET Core & .NET Core Identity. Does it work with .NETFramework?

I've been searching online and I'm only finding people saying they have it not working with .NETFramework. Has anyone got it working.

Links to example code would be appreciated.

Comment: ID4 runs on .Net Core, but your API can be on anything, .NET 4.6, 4.7, or even PHP or Java or NodeJS, that is irrelevant.., here is a sample for nodejs: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/community.html#securing-a-node-api-with-tokens-from-identityserver4-using-jwks

Answer (score 1):

The default choice for protecting API in .Net 4.x is IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation. Unfortunately since 2017 it stays frozen while Microsoft refactored their Owin and Identity libs, so the preferred solution for ASP.NET 4.6+ becomes [IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation/) -- a fork, refactored according to the recent framework changes.

You may run Identityserver 4 itself by .Net 4.7 with ASP.NET Core packages installed, but .Net Core runtime is more organic choice.

Comment: If it was useful, please mark it the answer. It's a common practice to upvote the answer as well.